# Combination with repition, Representation techniques.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Consider the following Question:**
A bagel shop has onion bagels, poppy seed bagels, egg bagels, salty bagels, pumpernick bagels, sesame seed bagels, raisin bagels, and plain bagels. How many ways are there to choose

**e.)** a dozen bagels with at least three egg bagels and no more than two salty bagels?

> In this question, I do have the right answer but not sure if I have the most efficient representation. Later, I will elaborate much more complicated scenarios using the same technique, and ask what then?

**My Representation:**
First of all, I represent the information in my head as suggested by the book, by **Stars and Bars**, where the bars represent the division of source items (in this case the 8 types of bagels each have a bar), and stars that represent the items chosen (in our case the dozen bagels chosen). I represent it, to something like this,

$$|*||**|*\dots||$$

- If the right of bar have nothing in between, then the bagel represented by the bar is not selected.
- If the right of bar of $z$ times in between, then the bagel represented by the bar is selected $z$ times.

Now that we have a mental model of the problem, it is easy to see that we are just selecting the number of ways we are positioning $*$ or $|$. As the book mentioned, this can be reduced to a Combination problem, let $n$ be the number of choices (bagels types in our case), $r$ be the number of items chosen from $n$ bagels, (a dozen bagels in our case,

$${{n + r - 1}\choose{r}}$$

$n-1$ since $n$ objects only need $n-1$ bars to divide them.

That all being said, this is still not enough to solve the problem above, we need to factor in "no more than two salty bagels". With **Stars and Bars**, this can be represented by 3 cases, when when 0 salty bar is Thus we need to add the cases of 0 salty bagels, 1 salty bagels, 2 salty bagels. Suppose the first bar is the salty bagel, and the second bar is the second bagel, the rest have $x$ to represent variable stars.

$$||*x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x$$
$$|*|*x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x$$
$$|**|*x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x$$

The combination of each are added below,

$${{7 + 12 - 3 - 1}\choose{12-3}} + {{7 + 11 - 3 - 1}\choose{11-3}} + {{7 + 10 - 3 - 1}\choose{10-3}}$$

**Problem:**
As you can see, the representation when the constraint is "at least $b$ of this element" is very easy. By having at least $b$ items of this element, there's only $r-b$ to choose, where $r$ is the number of element chosen. But to represent "no more than $c$ elements are to be chosen", I have to add instances when $0, 1, \dots, c$ elements are in the set. All the problems in this chapter of **Generalized Permutation and Combination** have this scenario, which if you ask me, does not sound very generalized. So,

1. How do you efficiently represent "no more than $c$ items of this elements" problems?
2. How do you represent when there's more than one "no more than $c$ items of this elements"? (e.g. salty bagels and egg bagels demand for their own maximum items). The only think I can think of now is adding probabilities when $(0 salty, 0 egg), (0, 1), \dots (0, max_{egg}) \dots (max_{salty}, max_{egg}$. But that is very unrealistic in computation standpoint since that will take $O(d^2), d = \max(max_{egg}, max{salty})$, which is very inefficient. Compared to all "at least $b$ elements" problems, it is $O(1)$. I have never seen the book in this current chapter describe such phenomena despite having the chapter title that it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative method for dealing with "no more than c" is to subtract. First find the number with any of that item; then find the number with more than c of that item; then subtract.

In your case you have 8 kinds of bagels and 12 bagels to choose, with a restriction of at least 3 egg bagels and at most 2 salty bagels.

You have to choose 3 of the egg bagels, so you really have 9 bagels to choose. You have to have 9 "take a bagel" instructions (the stars) and 7 "switch to a new kind of bagel" instructions (the bars), and need to arrange these in all ways so you get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 9+7 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
$$

If you now suppose you have to choose at least 3 salty bagels you then really only have 6 bagels to choose so you get
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 6+7 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
$$

But you actually wanted the ones with 2 or less salty bagels, so you subtract the number with more than 2 from the total to get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 9+7 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 6+7 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
$$

EDIT: If you had more than one of the "no more than c" restrictions, you may have to use inclusion-exclusion. The opposide of "no more than c of item A and no more than d of item B" is "more than c of item A OR more than d of item B". Hence you would need to subtract those with more than c of item A, and also subtract those with more than d of item B, and then add on those with too many of both.

Comment: That couldn't be any simpler. Thank you very much. Now I'm back to $O(1)$.

Comment: Quick question concerning $\binom{9+7}{7}$. Why isn't it $\binom{9+7}{9}$? If we have 7 stars and 9 bars then isn't it that we have $\binom{\text{stars + bars - 1}}{\text{stars}}$?

Comment: @JeelShah Your formula comes from having 9+7 objects and choosing 9 of them to be stars. I have simply chosen 7 of them to be bars. Choosing which to be stars produces the same results as choosing the others to be bars. (In general I find I don't remember formulas, so instead I use  counting stories. This means my calculation will often look different to the "standard" formula, but it will give the same result.)